# Sign up form with data capture using local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project where the user sign up for the game and chooses which school attends (there are 4 possible schools to choose from. Once the school is chosen the user will play a simple game and if the user wins (there are 3 users playing simultaneously) then the school he selected at the beginning gets a point. At the ned of the game we can see how which school is winning.  I am planning to do this project in react, and the data capture would be using local storage. Is this possible at all without using backend?

Comment: So there are 3 different users playing simultaneously on 3 different machines? In that case you'd need a backend to keep track of the winner, OR manually look at the local storage individually of all 3 machines.

Comment: @adamz4008 it would be the same machine for those 3 different players.

Comment: Oh I see, if you want that info to persist after the window closes localstorage would help persisting the winner. Most of your app state would probably stay in React local state or React Context.